# Debugging external DLL in .NET

Tags: .net, debugging

I'm late binding my project to a DLL file and it is throwing an exception in a call to a DLL's method. This method is also used in another project (that is early binding to the DLL) and it works beautifully.

Is there a way I can debug the code within the method, from this new project, to see what's wrong?

I created this DLL and obviously have all the source code.

Both DLL files where coded using Visual Basic 2003 and .NET 1.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that your native DLL is written in C++, your .NET host is written in C# and you used Visual Studio, since you didn't provide the information.

In this case you can open up your DLL project in Visual Studio and use the [Attach to Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx) action on the Debug menu to debug an already running instance of your host application. Alternatively, you can set the project up to [start the app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/605a12zt%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) when you Run from within the DLL project.

I would imagine that you could also step through and land on breakpoints if you started out debugging from the .NET host application, but I've never done that.

Comment: Sorry for that lack of information and I already updated the question. Language is vb .net for both Dlls and I'm using .NET 1.1

Comment: @PedroC88 I think you have your answer now, 3 times over!

Comment: Yes, I was just clarifying for you, Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can debug the DLL - when you press <kbd>F5</kbd>, you'll be asked for the EXE file - just browse to your executable and debugging can be started.

If your DLL file use some other library or DLL file - all its dependencies have to be in the path where they can be found. Maybe you just didn't copy all of dependencies together with your DLL file.

Answer (score 1):

If the running process has the debug symbols (.pdb files) for its loaded DLLs available, you can open the project for the DLL in question and attach it to the running process (Debug -> Attach To Process).

Comment: Can you orient me more on this process?

Comment: @PedroC88: It depends a lot on how your projects are arranged and built.  This external DLL, is it a project included in a solution with the running application?  Or is just the DLL being referenced?  If the latter, you'll need a "debug build" of the DLL (to include PDB files) in the application's references in order to hit break points within its code.

Comment: Right now I'm trying to debug a DLL to which I'm late binding... (I am using reflection to create an instance of an object within). A parameterless method inside the object is throwing me an exception but this method called from another exe does not throw any. I want to debug this externall DLL from my exe to see what goes wrong. I have the source code of the DLL and both are written in VB and .NET 1.1